# Character equivalent of decimal in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I need to convert the numbers: decimal 13 and decimal 10 to their character equivalent in a bash shell script. The characters generated will be carriage return and line feed.

Any idea how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to give this answer, but in bash you can do:

```
nl=$'\12'
```

to make $nl be the string with a single newline.  (octal 12)
So you can populate from a decimal value with something like:

```
N=10
N8=$( printf %o $N )
eval nl="\$'\\$N8'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` twice, once to convert to octal, the other to convert to ascii

```
A=10
printf \\$(printf '%03o' "$A")
```

#### Proof

```
$ A=10;printf \\$(printf '%03o' "$A") | od -c
0000000  \n
0000001
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the simplest solution, but the first thing that comes to mind is to use printf.  Unfortunately, printf needs octal values, so you need to translate.  To print an A (ascii decimal value 65), you could use dc to compute an octal number and do:

```
$ A=65
$ printf \\$( echo 8o${A}p | dc )
```

If you are willing to use perl:

```
$ perl -e "print chr $A"   # print character whose decimal value is stored in shell variable A
$ perl -e 'print chr 10'   # print a carriage return
```

Comment: Is there any way I could save the generated characters ?

Comment: Store them in a file or put them in a variable.  A=$( printf \\$( echo 8o65p|dc )) should assign "A" to A.  You'll have trouble with the newline though, since $() trims a trailing newline and you'll get a null string.

Comment: Here's a terrible way to get whitespace into the variable A: eval "$( printf "A='\\$( echo 8o10p|dc )'" )"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe regex is something for you:

```
msg="13 ways to leave your lover is a top 10 hit for 1310 days"
stp1=${msg//10/\\n}
echo -e ${stp1//13/\\r}
```

result:

```
 ways to leave your lover is a top 
 hit for 
 days
```